# How can I monitor other mount namespace?

Tags: linux, namespaces, mount

I'm developing daemon monitoring SD card directory with using fanotify.

But, all users have their own mount namespace, so daemon can't receive fanotify event though user app writes SD card (same directory with above).

How can I monitor all mount namespace?

Answer (score -1):

Each mount point needs to be manually added by fanotify_mark(). 
Here is is a good [example](https://github.com/proger/fanotify_watch/blob/master/fanotify_watch.c#L175-L200):